# C++ Exceptional Handling Wrong Output

Tags: c++

I wrote following C++ code in Dev C++:

```
// Program for exception handling

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 0;
    int c;

    // try block activates exception handling
    try
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            // throw custom exception
            throw "Division by zero not possible!";
            c = a / b;
        }
    }
    catch (char* ex)
    {
        cout << ex;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be "Division by zero not possible". But the output is "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'.

How to rectify this code?

Comment: After the if statement, not before ;)

Comment: Not the problem at hand, but `c = a / b;` should be *after* the `if`

Comment: Type of `"Division by zero not possible!"` is `const char[31]`, not `char *`. You are not catching what you are throwing.

Comment: Also not that if you want to avoid "terminate called by ..." then you need to catch all possible exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

You are throwing a `char const*` but only catching a `char*`. Change the type in the catch statement to `char const*` and all is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The message says you have thrown an instance of char **const** * but you are catching an instance of **char** *

Try changing

`catch (char* ex)`

to

`catch (char const* ex)`

and see if that helps ...